# How to make proper array format using PHP

Tags: php, arrays

I need one help.I have some array value in one format but i need to change it to another format using PHP.I am explaining my code below.

```
$sql=mysqli_query($connect,"select * from db_restaurant_basic where member_id='".$member_id."'");
while($row=mysqli_fetch_array($sql)){
    if($row['image'] !=''){
        $mul_image=$row['multiple_image'];
        if($mul_image !=''){
            $arr=explode(',', $mul_image);
            for($i=0;$i<count($arr);$i++){
                $data[]=array("image".$i=>$arr[$i]);
            }
        }
    }
}
$result=array("data"=>$data,"imagepath"=>$imagepath);
echo json_encode($result,JSON_UNESCAPED_SLASHES);
```

The above code is giving below output.

```
{"data":[{"image0":"87az6yooi0ms4i_de021b24.jpg"},{"image1":"d0ub9h8if4dkj4i_a6d6c48a.jpg"},{"image2":"3j9tx0m9xj0dx6r_1080970_1405444569670737_1257617107_n.jpg"}],"imagepath":"http://localhost/spesh/upload/"}
```

But i need to remove all the `key` and the expected output is given below.

```
{"data":[{"87az6yooi0ms4i_de021b24.jpg"},{"d0ub9h8if4dkj4i_a6d6c48a.jpg"},{"3j9tx0m9xj0dx6r_1080970_1405444569670737_1257617107_n.jpg"}],"imagepath":"http://oditek.in/spesh/upload/"}
```

Please help me to do this.

Comment: Your expected output is not valid JSON.

Comment: Use a `foreach` loop and push the results into an array?

Comment: Ok,How can i display this without key.?

Comment: @AurelBílý :can you write your idea ?

Comment: Basically you cannot have a object property without a name for that property so `{"87az6yooi0ms4i_de021b24.jpg"}` is not valid as `{}` means object

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change this line:

```
$data[]=array("image".$i=>$arr[$i]);
```

To this:

```
$data[]=$arr[$i];
```

It will create valid JSON without the key.

The result will look like this:

```
{"data":["87az6yooi0ms4i_de021b24.jpg","d0ub9h8if4dkj4i_a6d6c48a.jpg",...
```

You can even reduce your code further, since you are basically copying the array `$arr` now:

```
while($row=mysqli_fetch_array($sql)){
    if($row['image'] !=''){
        $mul_image=$row['multiple_image'];
        if($mul_image !=''){
            $data=explode(',', $mul_image);
        }
    }
}
```

This will produce the same result.

Answer (score 1):

Just don't push a new array to the data array - only the value.

```
$sql=mysqli_query($connect,"select * from db_restaurant_basic where member_id='".$member_id."'");
while($row=mysqli_fetch_array($sql)){
    if($row['image'] !=''){
        $mul_image=$row['multiple_image'];
        if($mul_image !=''){
            $arr=explode(',', $mul_image);
            for($i=0;$i<count($arr);$i++){
                $data[] = $arr[$i]; // only value is pushed into data array
            }
        }
    }
}
$result=array("data"=>$data,"imagepath"=>$imagepath);
echo json_encode($result,JSON_UNESCAPED_SLASHES);
```